# Sitting arrangement - 3 men and their wives, 2 rows

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Three men and their wives sit randomly on 6 seats in 2 rows (each row has 3 seats).

1. What’s the number of different ways they can sit?
2. What is the probability that all the men sit in one row?
3. What is the probability that **every man** sits facing his wife?
4. What is the probability that **only one man** sits facing his wife? (I believe "at least one man" would do. Else it would be too complicated?)

I attempted solving the questions. The first one is surely right, but for the next two after too many tries, I solved them programmatically, that is - recursively listing all permutations and filtering the ones that fulfill the required condition.

My solution:

1. (6P6)=720
2. 72/720 = 1/10
3. 48/720 = 1/15
4. Couldn't solve it.

Can anyone assist on how to solve them mathematically? There should be an easy way that I'm missing out, the way I solved them probably gets me the right answer but it's not logical for a human to do.

Comment: For 2), assuming you insist on keeping with the sample space of size $6!=720$, you can first pick which row is the male row.  Then pick which man sits in the first seat of that row, which man sits in the second seat of that row, etc... then fill out the women's row as well.  $2\cdot 3!\cdot 3! = 72$.  For 3), pick who sits in the first row's first seat and place their spouse opposite them.  Repeat.  $6\cdot 4\cdot 2 = 48$.

Comment: For 4), pick which man sits across from his wife and pick which seat he sits in.  Now, in the first available remaining seat from the first row, pick who sits there and then pick a non-spouse of theirs to sit across from them.  Note that this forces the remaining two people to not be spouses and seat them.  $3\cdot 6\cdot 4\cdot 2\cdot 2 = 288$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are correct
2. There are two possible rows for all the men to sit on, and after choosing this row, there are $6$ ways to place the men in this row, and $6$ ways to place the women in the other row. So, we get $$\frac{2\cdot6\cdot6}{6!}=\frac1{10}$$
3. We simply choose which column each couple should be in, and which row the man sits in, so there are $3!\cdot8$ choices. So, we get $$\frac{3!\cdot8}{6!}=\frac1{15}$$
4. For this to happen, we first pick the couple that sits across from each other ($3$ choices), and then pick which column they do it in ($3$ choices), and which row the man is in ($2$ choices), and then allocate the rest of the seats. This is $4!-8$, since when one of the remaining couples sits across from each other, so does the other, so we count $8$ possibilities when this happens (which row is the man in for each couple, and which couple in which column). So, we get $$\frac{9\cdot16\cdot2}{6!}=\frac25$$